# Unable to migrate database in AWS using capistrano

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I am newbie to rails as well as deployment into production (AWS) using capistrano.

Its more than a day finding about this error and trying all the suggestions from SO and nothing is working out for me.

After configuring my `deploy.rb, capfile, production.rb and staging.rb` i ran three commands
1. `cap deploy:setup` -- successful
2. 'cap deploy:check' -- successful
3. 'cap deploy:cold' -- problem (below mentioned log)

what does it exactly mean by no role "ubuntu" exist ? and should i create new role or change the name in any file ?

```
** transaction: commit
  * 2014-07-11 17:18:07 executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "cd /home/ubuntu/apps/releases/20140711221716 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com"]
    [ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] executing command
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/g
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] ems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2201146833457417766__prepare__1495654531503866598__callbacks'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/app
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] s/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/releases/20140711221716/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] /home/ubuntu/apps/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 ** [out :: ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com] 
    command finished in 6635ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/apps/releases/20140711221716 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on ec2-54-88-174-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Please add your capistrano code.

Comment: Facing same issue. @rahul-dess how you fixed it?

Comment: hey @AmitPatel i moved to heroku ..could not solve it bud

Comment: @RahulDess Thanks ;) but I don't have any choice for now.

Comment: Cross referencing the issue with more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116454/unable-to-migrate-database-in-ec2-using-capistrano-fatal-role-ubuntu-does-n